# Grep expressions c

Tags: regex, grep

I am facing problem with getting regular expression for grep for these patterns:-

1).what words contain but do not begin with the string 'ps'.

2)What option has a description with the words "hide entries". (next line that contains some text after specified word.

I googled but didnt find it.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As grep deals with lines, you must process the source to have each word on its own line, then grep. If efficiency is not a question you can `grep "ps"` and pipe it to `grep -v "^ps"`.
2. I don't understand about hiding the entries. Can you provide an example of what you need from this option?

Comment: second point specifies need to get line before and after a particular match...thanks for help...though get the answer for 2nd one,using -B and -A swithces....

Comment: Ah, yes. That's it. Albeit not standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `grep -P '^(?!ps)'`.